# Send text highlight behind the text that comes after the highlight

Tags: css, highlight, overlap, bringtofront

I have a block of text, and I decreased the line height because I like it better that way. Sometimes the top of the h touches the bottom of the p above it, and that's okay.

My problem is that when I highlight text using `<mark>`, the `background-color` covers the lower half of the text on the line above it.

Please see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otVUV.png)

The text that comes after the highlight is placed on top of it, so I'm optimistic that there's a way to bring the before-text to the front as well.

I tried decreasing the opacity of `<mark>`, but that made the text itself transparent too.

I'd like to be able to send its background-color behind all text elements, if that's possible. Second place would be to decrease the opacity of just the background-color without affecting the marked text.

I made a snippet but it doesn't show the problem because I can't link to a font. Please see the linked image above to see the problem.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'charmonman';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman:wght@400;700&display=swap');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #7030A0;
  font-family: 'charmonman'
  line-height: 1.5;
}

mark {
  background-color: #fff2cc;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman:wght@400;700&display=swap');
</style>

<mark><strong>This text is a highlighted sentence.</strong></mark> This is much longer text. The beginning of this section is clear because it appears <strong>over</strong> the background color of the previously highlighted text, but the end of this section is half hidden by the background color of the highlighted text that follows it. <mark><strong>This is the highlighted text that partially covers the line that came before it.</strong></mark>
```

Comment: Better paste your code as well

Comment: I'm writing it! I had to post and then edit so that the code snippet thing would show up for me.

Comment: Not a good solution as you requested, but if you put `line-height: 2.3;` in `mark` styles it will increase the highlighted line and will show full text.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is caused by the way the `<mark>` element and its `background-color` behave. When you highlight text using the `<mark>` tag, the `background-color` is applied to the space that the text occupies. This can cause the highlighted background to overlap with the text on the line above it when the `line-height` is decreased.

You could try using a different approach that involves using `linear-gradient` as the background for the `<mark>` tag. The `linear-gradient` can create a similar effect to the highlight. Here's a potential solution:

```css
mark {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff2cc 100%, transparent 0%);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

In this case, the `linear-gradient` creates a highlight that covers 100% of the line height, and `background-repeat: repeat-y;` ensures that the highlight effect is applied to every line of text within the `<mark>` tag.

Here's your snippet with my proposed solution:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Charmonman';
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman:wght@400;700&display=swap');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #7030A0;
  font-family: 'charmonman';
  line-height: 1.5;
}

mark {
  background: #fff2cc;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman:wght@400;700&display=swap');
</style>

<mark><strong>This text is a highlighted sentence.</strong></mark> This is much longer text. The beginning of this section is clear because it appears <strong>over</strong> the background color of the previously highlighted text, <mark>but the end of this section is half hidden by the background color of the highlighted text that follows it. <strong>This is the highlighted text that partially covers the line that came before it.</strong></mark>
```

Comment: If the `mark` wraps multiple lines then your psuedo element gets messed up

Comment: In your snippet it only worked on the first instance of `<mark>`, in mine it worked on neither. :(

Comment: @Zachiah is right about multiple lines. The issue is when you go to a new line.

Comment: @BetuleSairafi I've edited my answer (and included your font in the snippet). Check this out. I've also "extended" the `<mark>`, so that the code snippet shows multiple lines taken into account

Comment: That's perfect! I can't figure out why it's not working for me - it looks the same as before. The only change to my original code is in the <mark> tag, right?

Comment: you're using a background color for the `<mark> `, and this approach does not handle line breaks well. If the text within the `<mark>` tag spans multiple lines, the background color covers the entire block, not just the text. In my proposed solution, `background-repeat: repeat-y;` property ensures that this gradient is applied to every line of text within the `<mark>` tag, even if the text spans multiple lines.